# .Include() with .Take() and .Skip() creates a wrong SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I just want to load some "EventTypes" with their respective "Domains" with EntityFramework. The relation is N:1 that is, EventType reference a Domain with the column EventType.DomainID.

This works.

`IEnumerable data = await dbContext.EventTypes
.Include(x => x.Domain)                                                                    .ToListAsync();`

SQL code that it produces:

`SELECT [x].[ID], [x].[DomainID], [x].[HtmlEventDescription], [x].[Name], [x].[Url], [d].[ID], [d].[DebugHost], [d].[Host]
FROM [EventTypes] AS [x]
INNER JOIN [Domains] AS [d] ON [x].[DomainID] = [d].[ID]`

But now I want to include pagination.

`IEnumerable data = await dbContext.EventTypes.Include(x => x.Domain)                                                                    .Take(pageSize)
.Skip(pageIndex * 10)                                                                  .ToListAsync();`

SQL it produces is alright, tried it in SQL manager, but it returns only columns for domains.

`SELECT [d].[ID], [d].[DebugHost], [d].[Host]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [x].[ID], [x].[DomainID], [x].[HtmlEventDescription], [x].[Name], [x].[Url]
    FROM [EventTypes] AS [x]
) AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Domains] AS [d] ON [t].[DomainID] = [d].[ID]
ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
OFFSET @__p_1 ROWS`

But now it also produces an exception.

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory:Error: An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occured while reading a database value for property 'EventType.DomainID'. The expected type was 'System.Int32' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.`

I wonder what I'm doing wrong. 
Why is EF creating a query with just "Domain" properties eventhough I'm querying an EventTypes table with `dbContext.EventTypes`? I suspect that's why it is trying to cast string to int, because there is no DomainID column in the result in first place and it's probably trying to cast the string column of `Domain.DebugHost` or `Debug.Host` to `EventType.DomainID`.

Comment: Usually on pagination you first `Skip` some records then `Take` some records for current page. Have you tried to change call order?

Comment: You have the skip/take reversed. It should be .`Skip(pageIndex * 10).Take(pageSize)`

Comment: Also shouldn't you do `Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)`?

Comment: Oh my gawd, you are right. EF could tell me something more precise at least....juharr: yes, thank you! :)

Comment: Btw, it's good to specify that you are using EF *Core* in tag and until it gets stable (which it currently is not), the exact version.

Comment: I added the asp.net-core tag, did not find an EF core or anything similar...

Comment: @Mirek: It may sound "absurd", but the tag is named [tag:entity-framework-core] with `-core` added to the old tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was advised in comments:

The bug is that these lines

`.Take(pageSize)
.Skip(pageIndex * 10)`

must be in a different order. Skip must be before Take. Now it works correctly.

`.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
.Take(pageSize)`